# Basic Haskell IO Monad FilePath join

Tags: haskell, monads

Exploring the basics of Haskell IO Monads, I would like to create a handle to a temporary file. The temporary directory FilePath is within an IO context, and I need to map a function into this context to join the path with a filename.

My first attempt was to use fmap, however, the FilePath was joined in the reverse order. Is it possible to fmap without reversing the order?

My second attempt works, but it feels overly complicated. Any suggestions how this can be improved?

Haskell is beautiful.

```
import System.Directory(getTemporaryDirectory)
import System.FilePath.Posix(joinDrive)

-- fmap is simpler, but the join order was reversed
createTempFile :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
createTempFile filename = fmap (joinDrive filename) getTemporaryDirectory

-- instead, I do this, but it feels overly complicated
createTempFile' :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
createTempFile' filename = getTemporaryDirectory >>= ((\x y -> return (joinDrive y x)) filename)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer to your question is to use the flip function, e.g.

```
createTempFile filename = fmap (flip joinDrive filename) getTemporaryDirectory
```

You could also use a section:

```
createTempFile filename = fmap (`joinDrive` filename) getTemporaryDirectory
```

Comment: flip is exactly what I need! I believe that sectioning joinDrive turns it into an operator - or something like that.

Comment: @indi Essentially, yes.  You can't alter its fixity (to my knowledge) but it does allow you to use it in infix notation just like an operator, it's a very handy piece of syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Your first solution results in reverse join because you are passing the `filename` as first argument of `joinDrive`. This can be expanded to see that the result is correct:

```
fmap (joinDrive filename) getTemporaryDirectory
```

can be rewritten with:

```
fmap (\f -> joinDrive filename f) getTemporaryDirectory
```

that is not what you want. What you need is something that expands to:

```
fmap (\f -> joinDrive f filename) getTemporaryDirectory
```

in Haskell you can write this by using the infix notation:

```
fmap (`joinDrive` filename) getTemporaryDirectory
```

As side note, you should consider using `</>` instead of `joinDrive` because `getTemporaryDirectory` doesn't return the temporary directory with path separator at the end:

```
 import System.Directory(getTemporaryDirectory)
 import System.FilePath.Posix((</>))


 createTempFile :: FilePath -> IO FilePath
 createTempFile filename = fmap (</> filename) getTemporaryDirectory
 -- that expanded is fmap (\f -> f </> filename) getTemporaryDirectory
```